# Glue Data Catalog schema in wrong order

Tags: aws-glue

I have a PySpark ETL job which writes parquets to an S3 bucket and partitions them, like this:

`df.write.partitionBy("partitioncol).mode("append").parquet(s3_path)`
It is essentially one new partition per day.

When I add a new column to the source data, it gets added in the correct place in the parquet file. However, when I run my crawler to update my glue data catalog table, the new columns are added last. I need them to be added as the parquet looks like in the new partition.

Below is how my crawler schema_change_policy is set in the CDK Stack

```
 schema_change_policy=CfnCrawler.SchemaChangePolicyProperty(
      delete_behavior="LOG",
       update_behavior="UPDATE_IN_DATABASE"
   ),
```

For example, the parquet file looks like this when querying with S3 select, where "NewTest" is my new column.

Intially, parquet file 1 in partition 1 looks like this:

```
{
  "requestId": "someGuid",
  "testType": "TEST", 
  "CurrentlyProcessedFileName": "ABC123"
}
```

When I run my crawler to create my table, the schema looks like:

```
1   requestid   string

2   testType    string 

3   currentlyprocessedfilename  string
```

So far everything works as exepcted.

However, when I modify my source file and write another parquet to another partition which looks like below, with new column "NewTest":

```
{
  "requestId": "someGuid",
  "testType": "TEST",
  "NewTest": "NewTest", 
  "CurrentlyProcessedFileName": "EDF567"
}
```

And when I then run my crawler to update the table and schema, the schema looks like:

```
1   requestid   string

2   testType    string 

3   currentlyprocessedfilename  string

4   NewTest     string
```

As you can see, NewTest was added at the very end. I do however want the new column to be added in the same order as my latest parquet I write.

Tried using this setting without success:
Update all new and existing partitions with metadata from the table
Partitions inherit metadata properties — such as their classification, input format, output format, SerDe information, and schema — from their parent table.

Comment: This is something you cannot control, also I see you should not face issues when your order changes as it is parquet.Have you tried manually editing the schema order in Glue console if you need it?

Comment: Thank you @PrabhakarReddy for your reply. Yes, it works fine when I manually change the order.

I would however like to have more work in a more automated way. Even just dropping the table and rerunning the crawler doesnt change the order of columns.